# How to disable for GET and PUT in spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have GET,POST,PUT and DELETE mappings in spring boot app, I have added spring security and disabled the csrf for POST like below

```
httpSecurity.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().
            antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users/post").
            permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated();
```

how can I disable it for GET and PUT methods like above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Bean
public CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {

  return new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
}
```

Then add your paths that you want to disable `CSRF` token to the `ignoringAntMatchers` method.

```
httpSecurity
    .csrf()
    .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
    .ignoringAntMatchers("/users/post" , "/admin/post");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably confusing the functionality of authorizeRequests().

You can break down your code in two separate blocks and have the same functionality.

```
http
        .csrf()
            .disable();
http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users/post")
                .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
```

So, when you disable csrf, this applies for every Http method.

The authorizeRequests does not refer to csrf, you use it to set authorization filters for your controllers.